# System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Any' - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

Using Visual Basic // C#

I'm trying to search through my stored arrays for a match to the user input. 
For example, the user has stored the data for a USB, and now wishes to bring that information back up.

FULL CODE BELOW

I'm already using IndexOf to find the array index, but now i want to search that index for a match to the user's input. 
This line of code:

```
if (ProductNameArray.Any(usersearch.Contains))
```

has come up with the error that

> System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Any'

but it has worked in other code for me.

I cannot seem to figure this out, any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace Prac_Test3
{


class Program
{
     // Constants
        const int SIZE_OF_PRODUCT_CODE = 4;
        const float CATEGORY_A_MARKUP = 10.0F;
        const float CATEGORY_C_MARKUP = 33.3F;
        const float CATEGORY_P_MARKUP = 15.0F;
        const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100;


    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("--------------> Menu <------------");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add a product                (a)");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Find a product               (f)");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Enter the quantity in stock  (q)");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Delete a product             (d)");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Calculate and display values (v)");
        Console.WriteLine("6. Exit                         (x)");
        Console.Write("\r\nEnter your selection: ");
    }
    static void AddProduct( string[] ProductNameArray, string[] ProductCodeArray, float[] WholesalePriceArray, ref int NextAvaliablePosition)
    {
        string ProductName = "";
        string ProductCode = "";
        string ProductCategory = "";

        float WholesalePricePerItem = 0.0F;

        bool ParseResult = false;
        bool ErrorFlag = false;

        string UserResponse = ""; 

        do
        {
            ErrorFlag = false;
            Console.Write("Product Name                : ");
            ProductName = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ProductName == "")
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Product Name must not be left blank.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                ErrorFlag = true;
            }
        } while (ErrorFlag);

        do
        {
            ErrorFlag = false;
            Console.Write("Product Code                : ");
            ProductCode = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ProductCode == "")
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Product Name must not be left blank.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                ErrorFlag = true;
            }
            else if (ProductCode.Length != SIZE_OF_PRODUCT_CODE)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Product Code must be exactly four characters.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                ErrorFlag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ProductCategory = ProductCode.Substring(0, 1);
                ProductCategory = ProductCategory.ToUpper();
                if (ProductCategory != "A" && ProductCategory != "C" && ProductCategory != "P")
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Product Code must start with A, C or P.");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    ErrorFlag = true;
                }
                else if (!(Char.IsDigit(ProductCode[1])) && !(Char.IsDigit(ProductCode[2])) && !(Char.IsDigit(ProductCode[3])))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Product Code  must be A, C or P followed by three digits.");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    ErrorFlag = true;
                }
            }
        } while (ErrorFlag);

        do
        {
            ErrorFlag = false;
            Console.Write("Wholesale price per item ($): ");
            UserResponse = Console.ReadLine();
            ParseResult = float.TryParse(UserResponse, out WholesalePricePerItem);
            if (ParseResult == false)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                ErrorFlag = true;
            }
            else if (WholesalePricePerItem <= 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Wholesale price must be a number greater than 0.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                ErrorFlag = true;
            }
        } while (ErrorFlag);
    }
    static void FindProduct(Array ProductNameArray)
    {

        int search = -1;
        string usersearch;

        usersearch = Console.ReadLine();
        search = Array.IndexOf(ProductNameArray, usersearch);

        if (search >=0)
        {
            if (ProductNameArray.Any(usersearch.Contains))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" details blah blah");
            }
        }
        else if (search <0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No record exists.");
        }
```

Comment: You sure you add `System.Linq` namespace? What is your .NET Framework version?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this, could you please explain a bit more? (I'm a first year programming student)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need `using System.Linq;` for that to work.

[`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an extension method defined in LINQ.

Also, pay attention to the type of `ProductNameArray`. If it is defined as `Array` (and not `string[]`, for example), the compiler has no way of inferring that, when enumerated, it'll yield `string`s.

In that case, you'd have to write:

```
if (ProductNameArray.Cast<string>().Any(usersearch.Contains))
```

---

Edit: OK, looking at the code it seems that the problem is the one described above.

You'll have to change the signature of the `FindProduct` method from

```
static void FindProduct(Array ProductNameArray)
```

to

```
static void FindProduct(string[] ProductNameArray)
```

or use the `.Cast<string>` method.

I'd personally prefer changing the method's signature, since the `ProductNameArray` passed to it seems to really be a `string[]`.

Comment: I've got this lot of code at the very top of my code
    
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Shandep Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Shandep Perhaps it's a good idea to include all your code in the question.

Comment: this part is inside a method, i didn't think that the rest of it would be relevant. what parts do you recommend i add in to my question?

Comment: @Shandep I don't know the code, so I cannot know which parts of it are relevant. Ideally you'd post all the code, to see, for example, that there's no custom `Array` class in the current scope that hides the `System.Array` class.

Comment: @Shandep OK, I think I know what's going on - what's the type of `ProductNameArray`?

Comment: Its a string. (i did edit my question, but it's not showing that I have, unsure if it has changed for you)

Comment: @Shandep OK, see if the update to my answer solves the issue.

Comment: It has - thank you for your help. Sorry about all the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

`Any()` is an extension method in `System.Linq` namespace. You have to add `using System.Linq;` so that you can use it.

```
namespace Your.Namespace
{
    using System;
    using ... // your other usings
    using System.Linq;

    public sealed class YourClass
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            // ...
            yourArray.Any()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have that, along with other things, at the very top of my code.

Answer (score 1):

**Add below to you code**

```
using System.Linq;
```